# Height for a form with paginations

Tags: forms, popup

I'm working on a form which has a pagination. The form is in a window.

I'm not sure what to do with window's height. Should I change it regarding the form's height or keep it?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I find it interesting that you have a multi-step form in a modal. Can you provide context for this form and perhaps a quick user flow. Modals tend to be used to elicit crucial decisions from a user or to provide important information regarding the upcoming experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the Window size. It reinforces the impression that the form belongs together. As the size changes, so does the position of the buttons, which can be annoying.